# autorepfixer not working for webpack

Tags: webpack, autoprefixer

I have the following web pack configuration below but the issue is that the generated css file does not contain any vendor prefixes.
Can someone point me in the right direction as to what i have missed?

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var precss       = require('precss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./app/main.js'],
  output: {
    path: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? './dist' : './build',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { 
        test: /\.js$/, 
        exclude: /node_modules/, 
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
        }
      },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']) }
    ]
  },
  postcss: function () {
        return [autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    }), precss];
  },
  plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css", {
            allChunks: true
        })
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a trouble getting autoprefixer to work with Webpack and ExtractTextPlugin as well, but I finally got it to work with the following webpack.config.js:

```
require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const processHTMLPages = require('./processHTMLHelper.js');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('./style/style.css');
const plugins = [
  extractCSS,
].concat(processHTMLPages());

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    './source/index.js',
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel'],
      },
      {
        test: [/\.scss$/i, /\.css$/],
        loader: extractCSS.extract(['css?-minimize', 'postcss', 'sass']),
      },
    ],
  },
  postcss: [autoprefixer()],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.es6'],
  },
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/build`,
    filename: 'index.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: `${__dirname}/build`,
  },
  plugins,
};
```

The key parts are the `css?-minimize` and not passing your browser config to `postcss: [autoprefixer()]`, but rather putting your browser config in a file in your root directory in a file named `browserslist` (for the reason why, see 'FAQ/No prefixes in production' section in `autoprefixer`'s  `[README.md][1]`. My `browserslist` file below. I have `Last 10 versions` for testing purposes, I know it is overkill.

Project root/browserslist:

```
# Browsers that we support

Last 10 versions
```